# Why I don't get the "Parsed with column specification" when using read.csv in r?

Tags: r, csv

I am following this [tutorial](https://joeystanley.com/downloads/180302-tidyverse_part1#getting_data_in_and_out_of_r) about the tidyverse. It starts with a very simple example that I can reproduce:

```r
library(readr)
menu <- read_csv("http://joeystanley.com/data/menu.csv")
#> Parsed with column specification:
#> cols(
#>   Category = col_character(),
#>   Item = col_character(),
#>   Oz = col_double(),
#>   Calories = col_double(),
#>   Fat = col_double(),
#>   Sugars = col_double()
#> )
```

But when I read a csv file from my own computer, I don't get the `Parsed with column specification` message. Why?

```r
library(readr)
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  var1 = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
                  var2 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1))
write.csv(df1,"./df1.csv", row.names = TRUE)
read.csv(file = './df1.csv')
#>   X ID var1 var2
#> 1 1  1    a    1
#> 2 2  2    b    1
#> 3 3  3    c    0
#> 4 4  4    d    0
#> 5 5  5    e    1
```

I have tried using `options(readr.num_columns = 1)` but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using `read.csv` instead of `read_csv`. With the latter, it works as expected:

```r
library(readr)
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  var1 = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
                  var2 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1))
write.csv(df1,"./df1.csv", row.names = TRUE)
read_csv(file = './df1.csv')
#> Warning: Missing column names filled in: 'X1' [1]
#> Parsed with column specification:
#> cols(
#>   X1 = col_double(),
#>   ID = col_double(),
#>   var1 = col_character(),
#>   var2 = col_double()
#> )
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>      X1    ID var1   var2
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1 a         1
#> 2     2     2 b         1
#> 3     3     3 c         0
#> 4     4     4 d         0
#> 5     5     5 e         1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>